# What is the use of a read-only LDAP

Tags: database, ldap, readonly

If we cannot write to the LDAP there will be no information to read. If no information is in the LDAP, then what is the use of a read-only LDAP. For example if this read-only LDAP is used for user authentication, then a new user cannot write to this LDAP to be authenticated later. Can someone explain this.

Apologies if this is a dumb question, I cannot seem to find the answer elsewhere.

Comment: A read-only LDAP is used as a local cache, with writes being referred up to the master.

Comment: can you elaborate? you mean an application can't survive only with a read only LDAP?

Comment: Do you mean a 'user' with Read-only access or the LDAP server itself is Read-only? For the latter, it could be that it's getting updated via other means and the data can be read via standard LDAP protocols. Or, it's a decommissioned system being kept "on" for historical/archival purposes.

Comment: i meant the latter

Comment: @DesirePRG I don't know why you're asking me whether I meant something I didn't say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Often when there are more than one LDAP servers working together in a "replication" scheme.

Some of the LDAP servers may be Read-Only form a client perspective and only "Trusted Replication Partners" may write to the server.

There are also some LDAP implementations where a Read-Only Replica is exposed to some NOT Trusted security Domains.

-jim